# Centering text that works as a button in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to center the text inside my p element but I don't know how to do it.

Here is my HTML code

```css
        .header{
     width: 100%;
     height: 320px;
     background-color: #584F52;
     color: #CEC7C9;
     text-align: center;
     font-family: 'Century Gothic';
        }

        .header-text{
     padding-top: 30px;
     font-size: 150px;
        }

        a{
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #CEC7C9;
        }

        .header-support{
      font-size: 25px;
     padding-top: 0px;
     padding-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .button{
     width: 70px;
     background-color: #CEC7C9;
     color: #584F52;
        }

        p{
     text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<html>
        <head>
        <title> title </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="aicts.css">
        </head>
        <body>

        <div class="header">
     <div class="header-text"> <a href="#"> TITLE </a> </div>
     <div class="header-support"> support for the title </div>
     <div class="nav"> <div class="button"> <p> button </p> </div>
        </div>
```

I'm just new in web development and doing bunch of MOOCs so I still dont know the proper formatting and the right coding practices. If you don't mind, I will be glad if you will tell me what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Drop the `<p>` tag and add `text-align: center` to `div.button`. Also, you are missing the closing `</div>` for `div.nav`.

Comment: Look at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new `style` to the `div.button` as follows:

```
.button {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And modify the styling for `p` as shown below:

```
p {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can refer to the [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/f650rjqs/).

Comment: I would like to thank everyone for answering my questions. Thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you are doing is right but you gave fix width to the button.Just replace your css for button class with this:

```
.button{
width: 100%;
background-color: #CEC7C9;
color: #584F52;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This will work same as you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
p{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, p tag is for paragraph. In button you dont have paragraph, just text.
So you should not use p tag.

```
<div class="nav"><div class="button">button</div>

.button{
    width: 70px;
    background-color: #CEC7C9;
    color: #584F52;
    text-align: center;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Add margin:0 auto; in .button class.

```css
 .header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 320px;
    background-color: #584F52;
    color: #CEC7C9;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic';
    }

    .header-text{
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-size: 150px;
    }

    a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #CEC7C9;
    }

    .header-support{
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .button{
    width: 70px;
    background-color: #CEC7C9;
    color: #584F52;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

    p{
    text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="header">
    <div class="header-text"> <a href="#"> TITLE </a> </div>
    <div class="header-support"> support for the title </div>
    <div class="nav"> <div class="button"> <p> button </p> </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin: 0 auto;` to your `.button` class.

Also, there's no need for `<p>` tag inside `<button>` for text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
p{ width:100%;  text-align:center;}
```

or

```
p{  width:auto;  text-align:center;}
```

both of them work and without disturbing other elements.

Answer (score 1):

In below css class `.button` just you need to add `display: inline-block;` will solve the issue also you can copy and past below code.

```
.button{
 width: 70px;
 background-color: #CEC7C9;
 color: #584F52;
 display: inline-block;
}
```